# Transfer table from one database to another?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

i am working at my project where it collects information from two database, one  is supplied by the program lets name it DB Y and the other supplied by the user lets name it DB X , now i have an query that depends on companies which is on DB x so i want to transfer this table from DB x to DB y at run time and also checks if there is new updates in DB x and transfer them but i am confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the TransferDatabase method of the DoCmd object to link relevant tables and then run suitable append and update queries to synchronize.

Answer (score 2):

You can access a table in DB X without actually transferring the table into DB Y.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableInDbX IN 'C:\SomeFolder\DB X';
```

Comment: But it is a lot easier building append and update queries with a linked table yesno?

Comment: @Remou Yes, I would favor a link.  But when I went back to include that suggestion, saw you already did.

Comment: This method is much easier but still the query well not pass unless the full path is there unless Access uses App.Path then everything well be solved reason cause this program well be tested on my computer and non of them have the same user or directories

Comment: @Mahmoud Then perhaps you should link the table as Remou suggested, and manage the links on the users' systems with something like the  J Street Access Relinker from http://www.jstreettech.com/cartgenie/pg_developerDownloads.asp